Не могу понять, нужен дефис или нет?
У нас есть музыкальная группа из трёх человек и у нас есть название забавное — "мята лайм". Однажды нас на афише написали как "мята-лайм".
В связи с этим вопрос, а как правильно всё-таки писать: с дефисом или без?
Объясните, пожалуйста.

Приветствую вас на форуме! Название группы пишется с большой буквы. "Мята-лайм" — это оформление с дефисом, а не с тире. Подправьте, пожалуйста, свой вопрос.

а почему дефис нужен?

Никто пока не говорил, что дефис нужен. Просто в вопросе вы написали "нужно ли тире".

вижу вопрос поправили, это хорошо, а как в итоге правильно то? с дефисом мята-лайм верно?

"Мята-лайм" - одна группа, два существительных в названии... не, ну можете и запятую, почему нет.


Мне больше нравится раздельное написание: Группа "Мята  лайм". Красиво! И на название больше похоже, чем одно слово "мята-лайм".

Но вот правят запись, так как считают, что она не соответствует правилам орфографии. Обычно имеется в виду, что два нарицательных существительных должны писаться через дефис по образцам, приведенным у Розенталя, пункт 2, примечание.

В то же время по правилам  можно объяснить  и раздельное написание следующим образом. При дефисном написании мята-лайм второе слово является приложением/определением (мята лимонная), а вас не устраивает такое толкование.  У вас первое слово  является приложением/определением:  мята (мятный) лимон. Сравнить у Розенталя при раздельном написании: красавица (красивая) невеста.

Также читаются варианты по-разному. В словосочетании мята лайм два полнозначных ударения и пауза (возможно, это вам лучше подходит), а мята-лайм читается в одно слово без паузы.

Иначе говоря, нужно самим определиться, какое название вы хотите выбрать. Если раздельное, то можно объяснить орфографию по приведенному образцу.

Также следует учесть, что в названиях вы более свободны, чем в обычных текстах. Раздельное написание двух существительных не противоречит правилам орфографии  и допускается в определенных случаях.


Коротко можно ответить так.  Группа называется  «мята лайм», а не «мята-лайм». У этих вариантов разная грамматика  (словосочетание или слово) и разное произношение (в два слова или в одно слово).

А разве лимонная мята бывает?

Бывает! И синие зайцы бывают тоже)) Я ведь про обобщенное значение двух форм написания рассказываю, а не про мяту лимонную. Можно представить себе вкус мяты с лимоном  или лимона с мятой. Стоит также отвлечься от реального лексического наполнения, пусть речь идет о двух нарицательных существительных в принципе. Такое написание не запрещено. И не стоит думать, что форма написания (дефис или раздельно) — это всего лишь письмо по правилам. Нет, это еще разная грамматика, разное произношение, да и сама графика в этой теме важна (одно это или два слова).

благодарю! вы так всё чётко разъяснили! спасибо, теперь всё стало ясно и понятно ;-)
